# iPhone SE occasionally won't receive calls, I get missed call notification instead

Tags: iphone, call

At first I didn't think that was such a big problem, because it happened only every now and then, but now it's becoming frustrating, because I missed some important calls because of it.
Long story short: Sometimes I simply won't receive a call, instead I get a missed call notification, sometimes even few minutes after I was called.
'Do not disturb' is turned off, so that cannot be a problem. Sometimes I don't receive a call even **while** using a phone.
Has anyone else had such problems before?

Kind regards

Comment: Follow up to this thread: I got in touch with my carrier, they asked me to provide details of incoming calls that I didn't receive and apparently nothing was wrong, but the issue is still there. Furthermore I've noticed that most of the times - once even twice on the same day, I didn't receive an incoming call when the caller was using an iPhone. So it might be device's fault after all?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably worth rebooting the phone, just in case, & checking your carrier settings are up to date [Settings > General > About] but ultimately I'd speak to your carrier.

I had a similar issue last year which was resolved by getting a new SIM. Apparently, I'd had the old one so long I was several firmware generations behind & the new card just fixed it immediately.